# Cookie doesn't get deleted after deleting the cookie in PHP

Tags: php, oop, cookies

I am stuck at a point where I just want to create a logout script for my simple project but it doesn't work and I don't know why. Now here is my exact problem

I created a login script that is connected to my database in object-oriented PHP programming. My classes are structured as follows:

```
class Page
      class FetchPage extends Page
            object Auth
      class Auth extends Page
      class ChatCookie extends Page
      class Login extends Page
            object ChatCookie
```

It works like this:

1. `FetchPage` constructs the page by using methods of `Page` class

```php
function __construct() {
    $this->objAuth = new Auth();
    parent::generateHeader();
    parent::generateNav();

    var_dump($_COOKIE);

    if($this->load($_GET['ref']) === true) {            
        include_once $_GET['ref'].".php";
    } else {
        echo "Failed loading page contents of function load()..<br />";
    }

    parent::generateFooter();           
}
```

2. First, `parent::__constructor();` (the constructor of `Page`) is called

```php
protected function __construct() {
    $this->dbCon = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "chat") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($this->dbCon));
}
```

3. Constructor of `FetchPage` creates object of `Auth` and therefore calls this contructor

```php
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['usrID'])) {
        $this->guestip = get_ip_address();
        setcookie("guestip", "$this->guestip", time() + 86400, "/"); // guest ip on visit saved for 1 day
    }
}
```

4. Then the methods of Page `generateHeader()`, `generateNav()` and `generateFooter()` are called and create the basic HTML of the page
5. Whenever I check if a visitor is logged in, I use this little snippet

```php
if($this->objAuth->isLogged() == true) { // some code }
```

6. I have a `href` that leads to my file `logout.php`, in which I create a object of my class `Login` that then calls the constructor of `Login`

**Constructor of `Login`**

```php
function __construct() {
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    parent::__construct();
    $this->objChatCookie = new ChatCookie();
}
```

**logout.php**

```php
<?php

if($this->objAuth->isLogged() == true) {
require_once 'classes/Login.class.php';
$login = new Login();
    if($login->logoutUsr()) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> You logged out properly from the chat. All the data has been saved and is available to you when you log in next time!</div>';
        var_dump($_COOKIE);
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Oh snap!</strong> Something went completly wrong here. We have a <strong><em>false</em></strong> return.. that is harsh. Contact the website administrator please.</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Wait a moment..</strong> How about you first create an account, little fella?</div>';
}
```

7. Which then causes the creation of an object of my class `ChatCookie`

```php
function __construct() {
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
    parent::__construct();
    setcookie("online", false, time() + 86400, "/");

    // @function read() checks if there was a session before for this fUsrID or not
    if(isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
        //$this->readCookie();
    }
        $this->tmpCookieString = "";
    }
```

8. I then call the method in `Login` called `logoutUsr()` that calls the method `deleteCookie` of my `ChatCookie` class

**logoutUsr()**

```
function logoutUsr() {
        if($this->objChatCookie->deleteCookie()) {
            $this->objChatCookie = null;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**deleteCookie()**

```php
function deleteCookie() {
    // to do: query to update the timestampEnd in SQL

    $saved = false;
    $deleted = false;

    /* Save cookie data for later use */
    if($this->saveCookie()) {
        $saved = true;
    }

    /* Delete the Cookie and all data */

    foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            // no arrays created yet
        }

        setcookie("$key", null, time() - 3600);
        unset($_COOKIE[$key]);
    }

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['usrID'])) {
        $deleted = true;
    }

    if($deleted == true && $saved == true) {
        $this->objChatCookie = new ChatCookie();

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    var_dump($_COOKIE);
}
```

After this all is done I have the following output:

[image: Screenshot of output after these operations]

As you can see my `$_COOKIE` is an empty array but still after all is done the cookie is filled with all the values and keys from before. And I went through everything step by step and tried a lot but nothing worked.

After the logout there should be a different navigation as defined in my **nav.html** file:

```html
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <?php if($this->objAuth->isLogged() == false) : ?>
  <li <?php if($_GET['ref'] == "login") echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="index.php?ref=login">Login <?php if($_GET['ref'] == "login") echo '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>'; ?></a></li>
  <li <?php if($_GET['ref'] == "register") echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="index.php?ref=register">Register <?php if($_GET['ref'] == "register") echo '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>'; ?></a></li>
  <?php else : ?>
   <li <?php if($_GET['ref'] == "chat") echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="index.php?ref=chat">Chat</a></li>
   <li <?php if($_GET['ref'] == "inbox") echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="index.php?ref=inbox">Inbox <span class="badge">42</span></a></li>
  <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <?php if($this->objAuth->isLogged() == true) : ?>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php?ref=profile&id=<?php echo $_COOKIE['usrID']; ?>">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img/thumbs/<?php echo $_COOKIE['usrID'].".jpg"; ?>" /></a>
  <p class="navbar-text" style="margin-left: 0px;">Hello, User!</p>
  <li><a href="index.php?ref=logout">Logout</a></li>
  <?php else : ?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">not logged in..</a></li>
  <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I uploaded all my classes, the `login.php` and the `logout.php` to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xmEKT8ap).

What am I doing wrong, I cannot find the problem? Help very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You forgot to set the path when deleting the cookie. That is mandatory.

Comment: I saw different answers here where they put the exact code without the path. I will try this though and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: @machineaddict it worked. Can u just tell me if this is the proper way of deleting the cookie and successfully logging out? If you put this as a answer I will accept it, so that thread is closed

Comment: If you don't set the path, the cookie will be set to that relative url. Example: if you have `domain.com/my/special/url`, without the path, the cookie path will be set to `my/special/url`. Don't worry about the answer being accepted, it's the solution that matters.